# build error in launching flutter app in android studio

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on INE LX2 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[Fatal Error] strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.2.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] guava-27.0.1-jre.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] gson-2.8.5.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] gson-2.8.5.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] guava-27.0.1-jre.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10
      > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.2.2.
         > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.2.2/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.2.2.pom
            > Content is not allowed in prolog.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I get this as my error can you please find it and give a solution for it
when I am trying to launch the app following error appear